# What is the correct way to write native method signatures in Android NDK?

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have a working implementation of NDK library and corresponding Java-class. But I am not able to add overloaded method to that class. Currently my class contains:

```
package com.package;

public class MyClass
{
  public static native String getFileName();
  static
  {
    System.loadLibrary("mylib");
  }
}
```

My jniwrappers.cpp file has the following declaration:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_package_MyClass_getFileName(_JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz);
```

Up to this point everything is working fine. But next I modify my class:

```
package com.package;

public class MyClass
{
  public static native String getFileName();
  public static native String getFileName(int index);
  ...
}
```

And add to jniwrappers.cpp another declaration:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_package_MyClass_getFileName__I(_JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint index);
```

It compiles fine, Android application starts, does not get UnsatisfiedLinkError but when it calls the second method with the argument the first C++ function is being called but not the second. I have other methods with arguments in that class but none of them are overloaded so their respective JNI signatures do not contain arguments.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to add a `__` onto the end of the original getFileName function now that it is overloaded. Your 2 C function prototypes should now look like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_package_MyClass_getFileName__
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_package_MyClass_getFileName__I
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);
```

Comment: This was the first thing that I tried but something went wrong and I've got UnsatisfiedLinkError. Now I have retried this and got everything working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 27):

You should use `javah` tool to generate those signatures.

To use it, build the class file where you have your `native` function. You'll get a `class` file.

Run `javah -jni com.organisation.class_with_native_func`, it'll generate a header file for you.

It's far cleaner than editing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I should use. But still knowing the internals is very useful.

Comment: Or just use the -classpath command line switch to direct javah to the directory where you class file is compiled (ie: `javah -classpath /path/to/jar -jni com.package.name.YourClass`).