# How do you add an existing .so library to an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

There are several sources out there that say you should create a directory in src/main/ called jniLibs/armeabi and add your compiled .so file to this location. Then load your library using System.loadLibrary("nameOflib").

My issue is that when I define my function

```
public native long create();
```

create() gives the error:

Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_com_brendan_myApplication_MainActivity_create. 
Reports native method declarations in Java where no corresponding JNI function is found in the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio and which gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5.1, gradle 2.8

Comment: Is this [tag:gradle-experimental]?

Comment: not sure, it is one of the latest versions. I could try an older version to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Yes, there is a major difference in **build.gradle** file syntax. If you have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` then the [instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34521313/192373) by [piotrek1543](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4730812/piotrek1543) are just what you need. But don't expect Android Studio to resolve magically the native method declarations into a prebuilt library.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I can still call the jni methods even though there is an error saying 
"Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function".

Answer (score 1):

to solve that problem, just follow this steps and visit a link below:

> **Adding .so Library in Android Studio 1.0.2**
>
> 1. Create Folder "jniLibs" inside "src/main/"
> 2. Put all your .so libraries inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder
> 3. Folder structure looks like, 
>     |--app: 
>     |--|--src: 
>     |--|--|--main 
>     |--|--|--|--jniLibs 
>     |--|--|--|--|--armeabi
>
>     |--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
> 4. No extra code requires just sync your project and run your application. 
>     **Reference** 
>    https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle/tree/master/src/main
>
> From: [How to include *.so library in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio)

EDIT: I suppose that might not be problem with configuration, but with how you declare  native method signatures in Android NDK

Check this link: [What is the correct way to write native method signatures in Android NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031281/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-native-method-signatures-in-android-ndk)

Hope it help

Comment: This is what I am doing, and I am getting the error I described above.

Comment: please  look into link below "How to include..." there are some more answers

Comment: I have attempted these solutions with no luck.

Comment: I feel as though you are correct. I believe my libraries are loading correctly. I have worked with jni using Eclipse without issues so i wonder why my declarations are being stubborn.

Comment: i have .so file of other app that i have decompile i don't have native-lib.cpp file of that .so means i don't have native code i only have .so can i integrate and run it in my project because when i m runing the project this error is coming java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.krunal.camarademo.Libs.nativesystem.DMDHDR.getBracketedCount() (tried Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount and Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount__)