# Cannot resolve corresponding jni function opencv Android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

this is where i get error.I loaded correctly opencv library but i get this error.If i go in the ximgproc all native methods are red marked with "Cannot resolve corresponding jni function name_function".How can i resolve?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            //Log.i("prova",uri.toString());
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
           // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Mat g=new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(),bitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,g,true);
            SuperpixelSLIC x=Ximgproc.createSuperpixelSLIC(g,Ximgproc.SLIC,100,3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error that i get:

```
06-07 19:24:01.370 21090-21090/com.example.jt1995.provaemo E/art: No implementation found for long org.opencv.ximgproc.Ximgproc.createSuperpixelSLIC_0(long, int, int, float) (tried Java_org_opencv_ximgproc_Ximgproc_createSuperpixelSLIC_10 and Java_org_opencv_ximgproc_Ximgproc_createSuperpixelSLIC_10__JIIF)
06-07 19:24:01.370 21090-21090/com.example.jt1995.provaemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.jt1995.provaemo, PID: 21090
                                                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.ximgproc.Ximgproc.createSuperpixelSLIC_0(long, int, int, float) (tried Java_org_opencv_ximgproc_Ximgproc_createSuperpixelSLIC_10 and Java_org_opencv_ximgproc_Ximgproc_createSuperpixelSLIC_10__JIIF)
                                                                                 at org.opencv.ximgproc.Ximgproc.createSuperpixelSLIC_0(Native Method)
                                                                                 at org.opencv.ximgproc.Ximgproc.createSuperpixelSLIC(Ximgproc.java:452)
                                                                                 at com.example.jt1995.provaemo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:108)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6303)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3818)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3865)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5569)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521148/how-do-you-add-an-existing-so-library-to-an-android-studio-project#comment56815071_34521148), don't expect Android Studio to resolve magically the native method declarations into a library that is not built with gradle in integrated **externalNativeBuild**.

You can simply ignore this error message: your APK will still install the prebuilt library, and the native methods will be resolved at run time, even if Android Studio marks them red.

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")` annotation for this method, or for the entire class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
public class Ximgproc {
```

or configure this kind of Lint inspections for the given project, or for all projects:

[image: Preferences/Editor/Inspections]

But this does not resolve your runtime problem. You presumably have built your C++ code to produce a *native shared library*, say its name is **libXimgproc-native.so**. If it is packed correctly into your APK, it will be extracted to `/data/app-lib/com.example.jt1995.provaemo/` (you can check this path with `getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir`).

Your Java code should load this library before it tries to call the native methods of the **org.opencv.ximgproc.Ximgproc** class:

```
System.load("Ximgproc-native");
```

If all above assumptions are correct, the linker did not find an exported function in that library that implements the **createSuperpixelSLIC_0** native method. It tried both `Java_org_opencv_ximgproc_Ximgproc_createSuperpixelSLIC_10` and `Java_org_opencv_ximgproc_Ximgproc_createSuperpixelSLIC_10__JIIF`.

To check which methods are exported by the library, you can use the **nm** tool which is part of the NDK gcc toolchain. E.g. on my Mac this executable can be found at `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm`.

Run `…nm -D Ximgproc-native.so` and it will list, with **T**, all exported functions of your library.

I believe you will not find your function in this list. Maybe, the name is slightly wrong. Maybe, you set CFLAGS to **-fvisibility=hidden**, and did not explicitly declare the function as `JNIEXPORT` (or `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`). Maybe, the C++ function is not declared with `extern "C"`, and its name is mangled by the compiler.

If you use static libraries (**xxx.a**) as intermediates to assemble the resulting shared library, you should know that the linker can throw away unused external functions. In such case, using `LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES` instead of `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` may help.

Comment: This is what i get with "getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir " : /data/app/com.example.jt1995.provaemo-1/lib/arm

Comment: Another question, u wrote about "Ximgproc-native.so",in my folder project i have "jniLibs" folder with libs like "libopencv_ximgproc.a" but i wrote ".so",mine is ".a" @AlexCohn

Comment: In the end, you need a *shared library* which is ".so". You can use *static libraries* (".a") to build a shared library, but more often than not, these static libraries are a cause of confusion. If you use `ndk-build` to build "libopencv_ximgproc.a", you can simply change $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY) to $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) in an **Android.mk** file.